# Why is the reported case-fatality rate due to COVID-19 much higher in Italy than in China among individuals aged 70 years or older?

Tags: covid-19

Why is the reported case-fatality rate due to COVID-19 much higher in Italy than in China among individuals aged 70 years or older?

---

{1} stratified data by age group:

[image]

{1} inconclusively mentions two possible reasons:

> A second possible explanation for the high Italian case-fatality rate may be how COVID-19–related deaths are identified in Italy. Case-fatality statistics in Italy are based on defining COVID-19–related deaths as those occurring in patients who test positive for SARS-CoV-2 via RT-PCR, independently from preexisting diseases that may have caused death. This method was selected because clear criteria for the definition of COVID-19–related deaths is not available.
>
> A third possible explanation for variation in country-specific case-fatality rates are the differing strategies used for SARS-CoV-2 RT-PCR testing. After an initial, extensive testing strategy of both symptomatic and asymptomatic contacts of infected patients in a very early phase of the epidemic, on February 25, the Italian Ministry of Health issued more stringent testing policies. This recommendation prioritized testing for patients with more severe clinical symptoms who were suspected of having COVID-19 and required hospitalization. Testing was limited for asymptomatic people or those who had limited, mild symptoms. This testing strategy resulted in a high proportion of positive results, ie, 19.3% (positive cases, 21,157 of 109,170 tested as of March 14, 2020), and an apparent increase in the case-fatality rate because patients who presented with less severe clinical disease (and therefore with lower fatality rate) were no longer tested (case-fatality rate changed from 3.1% on February 24 to 7.2% on March 17). These more mild cases, with low fatality rate, were thus no longer counted in the denominator.

Other reasons could be a different SARS-CoV-2 strain or treatment differences.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNvbjl)
- [Reddit](https://redd.it/frp6hn)

---

References:

- {1} Onder, Graziano, Giovanni Rezza, and Silvio Brusaferro. "Case-Fatality Rate and Characteristics of Patients Dying in Relation to COVID-19 in Italy." JAMA (2020). http://jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?doi=10.1001/jama.2020.4683

Comment: Seriously, what are you looking for? A reference more reliable than a paper published in JAMA?

Comment: @BryanKrause seriously, a more conclusive paper.

Comment: I understand the desire for conclusiveness, but don't you think these authors would have published the more conclusive paper if they could have?

Comment: @BryanKrause there are many researchers working on covid-19. One inconclusive study doesn't mean that the same or other researchers will not concomitantly or soon have new insights. Aren't you a researcher yourself? I thought you'd understand.

Comment: Yes, I'm a researcher myself, so I understand clearly that inconclusive results are the norm in science, especially biology and medicine. It's likely that every reason that the authors give contributes to some degree, as well as overwhelmed health care facilities. Many of the uncertainties they report are not because these authors didn't think hard enough about the problem or have sufficient insight, they are uncertainties that cannot be resolved in the current data, and likely cannot be resolved ever.

Comment: @BryanKrause different teams may have access to different data. Or the same team may have access to more data in the future (e.g., more details on how the Chinese authorities count covid-19 cases). Etc.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons. One I've seen mentioned in the press (but hard to prove) is that because Italy's healthcare system was better than China's, they had managed to keep alive (before Covid-19) old people who would have been dead already in China. And these people had various health problems that made them quite susceptible to dying from the additional burden of a Covid infection.

Comment: @Fizz thanks, wouldn't be hard to provide with some access to patient data

Comment: For the whole population, including the dead who didn't die of Covid in China, but *could have, had they lived long enough otherwise*...  Good luck getting a grant for that.

Comment: @Fizz my former colleagues got a fair amount of grants for https://mimic.physionet.org/ so totally possible. Especially for a pandemic affecting millions of people. There are probably many covid-19-related grants already, and many other sources of fundings.

Comment: Yeah, I can totally see authoritarian China approving access to data (never minds funds) for a study that intends to prove their CPC-provided healthcare system sucks worse than you might think right now.

Comment: @Fizz do you think patient data in Chinese hospitals have never been analyzed in a study?

Comment: @Fizz I don't think you need to speculate about health care quality, it's probably sufficient just from demographics: there are a lot more old people in Italy than China. This was Explanation #1 in the paper Franck quotes from.

Comment: @BryanKrause I'm asking about case-fatality rate so having more >70yo patients wouldn't explain.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for speculation since there aren't any other papers that address this issue.

I can think of a number of reasons in addition to the ones mentioned in the paper.

We know medical workers were hit higher than than the general population. This implies a higher viral load initially leads to more severe disease. If more of the lung is affected initially there is less time to mount an immune response.

China removed the mildly infected and asymptomatic infected quickly by large scale testing. When testing by PCR was unavailable they even used chest CT scans for screening.

It's culturally acceptable to wear face masks after the sars epidemic in China. You didn't see this in Italy. But it reduces viral shedding into the environment.

Italians are more touchy than Chinese. Whereas a handshake in China might do, Italians are more likely to face kiss and engage in other more dangerous close contact acts.

The one child policy also meant that the population has fewer mobile vectors of disease moving around viz younger children.

Household transmission was kept at 10% in Guangdong. If Italy failed to test early and frequently this would have increased this rate of transmission, with higher viral loads.

So I conclude that death rates were higher in the over 70s because numerous factors lead to higher viral loads.

https://www.cnbc.com/2020/03/27/why-coronavirus-deaths-are-higher-in-italy-spain-than-in-china.html

Comment: Thanks. "Italians are more touchy than Chinese. Whereas a handshake in China might do, Italians are more likely to face kiss and engage in other more dangerous close contact acts." -> that shouldn't change the mortality rate

Comment: "You are asking for speculation since there aren't any other papers that address this issue." I don't know about that, there are already thousands of papers about covid-19.

Comment: If so why didn't you quote them? Already answered close contact leads to higher viral load.

Comment: got it, interesting! Regarding the papers I was just mentioning there are many on covid-19, so it's possible that some already or soon address the question.

Comment: Also it's possible the Chinese figures are all curated to make the govt look good

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Please read [China's Wuhan city revises up total coronavirus death toll by 1,290](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-china-wuhan/chinas-wuhan-city-revises-up-total-coronavirus-death-toll-by-1290-idUSKBN21Z0DE) April 17, 2020